# I tried to run this code but it keeps giving an output of else condition

Tags: c++

The string `"Fahrenheit"` should have given an output of the first `if` statement, but instead it gives off an output of the `else` statement.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Temperature {
public:
    int temp;
    string unit;

    Temperature(int atemp, string aunit) {
        atemp = temp;
        aunit = unit;
    }

    void to_fahrenheit() {
        if (unit == "Fahrenheit") {
            cout << ((temp*1.8) + 32) << " Fahrenheit";
        } else if (unit == "Celsius") {
            cout << ((temp-32)*5/9) << " Celsius";
        } else {
            cout << "Converts only Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa.";
        }
    }
};

int main()  {
    Temperature temp1 (10,"Fahrenheit");
    temp1.to_fahrenheit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the constructor it should be `temp = atemp;` and not the other way.

Comment: and use intializer lists

Comment: You are not saving the parameter.  Also you are doing a double conversion - F should produce C and vice versa.  F shouldn't produce F.

Comment: I tried the change @kotatsuyaki commented and it was the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Yea, I missed that one. Thank you for pointing that out! @cup

Answer (score 1):

Your assignments are the wrong way round

```
Temperature(int atemp, string aunit)    {
    atemp = temp;
    aunit = unit;
}
```

should be

```
Temperature(int atemp, string aunit)    {
   temp = atemp;
   unit = aunit;
}
```

This a logic error not a syntax error.

The best way to write this code is to use an *initialiser list*

```
Temperature(int atemp, string aunit) : temp(atemp), unit(aunit) {
}
```

That makes it impossible to make the mistake you made.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about initializer list, I will use that next time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is to assign the variables properly.

```
 Temperature(int atemp, string aunit)    {
temp = atemp;
unit = aunit;
}
```

In C++, = operator follows right to left assignation.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my code and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

your code are wrong at this line.

```
atemp = temp;
aunit = unit;
```

Must be:

```
temp = atemp;
unit = aunit;
```

Thank

Comment: I changed my code and it was indeed the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor implementation is wrong, you should assign the input parameters to class member variables rather than other way around:

```
Temperature(int atemp, string aunit) 
   : temp{atemp}
   , unit{aunit} 
{
}
```

Comment: Okay,  I have changed it as you told and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Public variables should be assigned a value passed as a parameter in the constructor. So, in Temperature Constructor:

```
temp = atemp and unit = aunit
```

Final code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Temperature
{
public:
int temp;
string unit;
Temperature(int atemp, string aunit)
{
    temp = atemp;
    unit = aunit;
}
void to_fahrenheit()
{
    if (unit == "Fahrenheit")
    {
        cout << ((temp * 1.8) + 32) << " Fahrenheit";
    }
    else if (unit == "Celsius")
    {
        cout << ((temp - 32) * 5 / 9) << " Celsius";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Converts only Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa.";
    }
}
};

int main()
{
Temperature temp1(10, "Fahrenheit");
temp1.to_fahrenheit();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood the mistake and I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Temperature   {
public:
    int temp;
    string unit;
    Temperature(int atemp, string aunit)    {
    //atemp = temp;
    //aunit = unit;
// change the assignment you will get your desired output
    temp = atemp;
    unit = aunit;
    }
    void to_fahrenheit()    {
        if  (unit == "Fahrenheit")   {
            cout << ((temp*1.8) + 32) << " Fahrenheit";
        } else if (unit == "Celsius") {
            cout << ((temp-32)*5/9) << " Celsius";
        } else  {
            cout << "Converts only Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa.";
        }
    }
};

int main()  {
    Temperature temp1 (10,"Fahrenheit");
    temp1.to_fahrenheit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).